# @react-google-maps/api map object is not available

Tags: typescript, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I'm trying to build a feature using the amazing @react-google-maps/api but i'm get stucked on a problem.

I need to access a function called `getBounds` from `mapInstance` but after load my map using the library it looks like the function is not available. I can print the whole `mapInstance` on the console and access this function from there but it not works from my code :(

I'm providing this minimum example to show you guys the problem I'm facing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-jackson-i3z1r?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

It was not an error with `@react-google-maps/api`, it was actually a mistake that I made with React.

Basically, the function is setted properly but the map bounderies is not available when I was trying to get it.

The code sample is availabe on the following link:

https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/discussions/2458